# Applescript to copy folder (and contents) to current location?

Tags: macos, finder, applescript

I am trying to create a button on my Finder toolbar powered by applescript to make a copy of a set folder (e.g. /Users/James/doc) and all files/subfolders within it to the current location in Finder.

The motivation for this is that I have a LaTeX documentation format with subfolders such as img that I normally add to every new coding project in a folder called doc, so having a button that adds this folder would save me time instead of manually copying it across each time.

My applescript skills are not very good, I have tried:

**1)**

```
set x to ((the target of the front window) as text) as alias
set y to ((folder "Users/James/doc") as text) as alias

tell application "Finder"
    duplicate y to x
end tell
```

the error I get from running this first attempt is: `Can’t make target of window 1 of «script» into type text.`

**2)**

```
tell application "Finder"
    duplicate folder "Users/James/doc" to (the target of the front window)
end tell
```

which when run gives the error `Finder got an error: Can’t set target of window 1 to folder "Users/James/doc".`

(PS: I already know [how to turn the applescripts into Finder buttons](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112313/best-way-to-create-icons-buttons-in-finder-toolbar-matching-osx-feel))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script should work:

```
property y : POSIX file "/Users/James/doc" as alias

tell application "Finder"
    set x to target of window 1 as alias
    duplicate y to x
end tell
```

By setting `y` as a property (and as an alias), the script should not break by simply renaming or moving the the folder to be copied.